# Why is the Android tablet emulator so slow? Is there way to speed it up?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [slow android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

My tablet is not here yet, which is why I have to use the emulator for development for now. But it is soooo slow, and it is almost not usable. Does anybody has any trick to speed it up a bit?

I am working on a very decent machine:

MacBook Pro, 2.4 Intel Core 2 Duo, 8G Memory, SSD.

Thanks

---

There are a number of answers to a near identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator).

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but the tricks to speed up the emulator did not do the job for speeding up the tablet one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is slow because it is emulating an ARM processor on an x86 machine. This means that:

1. All hardware acceleration is lost and has to be emulated in software, and
2. All the system calls have to be restructured.

Google is working on better ways of doing graphics, but nothing is released yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are no tricks as of yet, and no other Emulators that you can use, Until Google actually makes one.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of answers to a near identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator).

Answer (score 1):

I know a trick. Upgrade to a better CPU, preferably one not subject to laptop limitations.

Comment: I too would like to recommend development machines for performing development.